# MACSEC frames not valid

Tags: linux, networking, cryptography

I'm using `wpa_supplicant` to set up a MACSEC secure wired channel.  On an Ubuntu x86 system, this works.  But on an Arm64 Alpine system, the MKA appears to succeed and the interface is set up, but no IP4 traffic goes over the MACSEC link.  The `InPktsNotValid` counter goes up.  AFAICT from the driver source code, this means either there was a memory allocation failure while processing the frame or decryption failed; unfortunately, the driver swallows the actual error.

The `wpa_supplicant` config file is the same on all the systems involved:

```
$ cat test.config 
no_ctrl_interface=yes
eapol_version=3
ap_scan=0
fast_reauth=1

network={
    key_mgmt=NONE
    eapol_flags=0
    macsec_policy=1
    mka_cak=0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF
    mka_ckn=6162636465666768696A6B6C6D6E6F707172737475767778797A303132333435
    mka_priority=128
}
```

I run wpa_supplicant like this:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -ieth0 -Dmacsec_linux -ctest.config -d
```

Here is a sample of the wpa_supplicant output:

```
KaY: to enpacket and send the MKPDU
*** MKA Basic Parameter set ***
    Version.......: 1
    Priority......: 128
    KeySvr........: 1
    MACSecDesired.: 1
    MACSecCapable.: 2
    Body Length...: 60
    SCI MAC.......: d4:25:cc:b0:25:21
    SCI Port .....: 1
    Member Id.....: - hexdump(len=12): ea fd 2f b9 9d f6 e2 17 38 0d d8 b1
    Message Number: 34069
    Algo Agility..: - hexdump(len=4): 00 80 c2 01
    CAK Name......: - hexdump_ascii(len=32):
     61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f 70   abcdefghijklmnop
     71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a 30 31 32 33 34 35   qrstuvwxyz012345
*** Live Peer List ***
    Body Length...: 16
    Member Id.....: - hexdump_ascii(len=12):
     9a fa 89 4d b4 3a 6b ac 2f b9 61 52               ___M_:k_/_aR    
    Message Number: 34451
macsec_linux: macsec_drv_get_receive_lowest_pn
macsec_linux: macsec_drv_get_receive_lowest_pn: result 1
*** MACsec SAK Use ***
    Latest Key AN....: 0
    Latest Key Tx....: Yes
    Latest Key Rx....: Yes
    Old Key AN....: 0
    Old Key Tx....: No
    Old Key Rx....: No
    Plain Key Tx....: No
    Plain Key Rx....: No
    Delay Protect....: No
    Body Length......: 40
    Key Server MI....: - hexdump(len=12): ea fd 2f b9 9d f6 e2 17 38 0d d8 b1
    Key Number.......: 1
    Lowest PN........: 1
    Old Key Server MI....: - hexdump_ascii(len=12):
     00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00               ____________    
    Old Key Number.......: 0
    Old Lowest PN........: 1
l2_packet_receive: src=d4:25:cc:b0:79:81 len=152
eth0_bridge: RX EAPOL from d4:25:cc:b0:79:81
RX EAPOL - hexdump(len=152): 03 05 00 94 01 80 60 3c d4 25 cc b0 79 81 00 01 9a fa 89 4d b4 3a 6b ac 2f b9 61 52 00 00 86 94 00 80 c2 01 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a 30 31 32 33 34 35 01 00 00 10 ea fd 2f b9 9d f6 e2 17 38 0d d8 b1 00 00 85 14 03 34 00 28 ea fd 2f b9 9d f6 e2 17 38 0d d8 b1 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 ff 00 00 10 f7 7c bc 50 24 8b bb af b0 c3 95 bc 29 ec 8c c5
eth0_bridge: Ignored received EAPOL frame since no key management is configured
l2_packet_receive: src=d4:25:cc:b0:79:81 len=166
RX EAPOL-MKA:  - hexdump(len=166): 01 68 76 68 76 68 d4 25 cc b0 79 81 5e ea 03 05 00 94 01 80 60 3c d4 25 cc b0 79 81 00 01 9a fa 89 4d b4 3a 6b ac 2f b9 61 52 00 00 86 94 00 80 c2 01 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a 30 31 32 33 34 35 01 00 00 10 ea fd 2f b9 9d f6 e2 17 38 0d d8 b1 00 00 85 14 03 34 00 28 ea fd 2f b9 9d f6 e2 17 38 0d d8 b1 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 ff 00 00 10 f7 7c bc 50 24 8b bb af b0 c3 95 bc 29 ec 8c c5
*** MKA Basic Parameter set ***
    Version.......: 1
    Priority......: 128
    KeySvr........: 0
    MACSecDesired.: 1
    MACSecCapable.: 2
    Body Length...: 60
    SCI MAC.......: d4:25:cc:b0:79:81
    SCI Port .....: 1
    Member Id.....: - hexdump(len=12): 9a fa 89 4d b4 3a 6b ac 2f b9 61 52
    Message Number: 34452
    Algo Agility..: - hexdump(len=4): 00 80 c2 01
    CAK Name......: - hexdump_ascii(len=32):
     61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f 70   abcdefghijklmnop
     71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a 30 31 32 33 34 35   qrstuvwxyz012345
*** Live Peer List ***
    Body Length...: 16
    Member Id.....: - hexdump_ascii(len=12):
     ea fd 2f b9 9d f6 e2 17 38 0d d8 b1               __/_____8___    
    Message Number: 34068
*** MACsec SAK Use ***
    Latest Key AN....: 0
    Latest Key Tx....: Yes
    Latest Key Rx....: Yes
    Old Key AN....: 1
    Old Key Tx....: No
    Old Key Rx....: No
    Plain Key Tx....: No
    Plain Key Rx....: No
    Delay Protect....: No
    Body Length......: 40
    Key Server MI....: - hexdump(len=12): ea fd 2f b9 9d f6 e2 17 38 0d d8 b1
    Key Number.......: 1
    Lowest PN........: 1
    Old Key Server MI....: - hexdump_ascii(len=12):
     00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00               ____________    
    Old Key Number.......: 0
    Old Lowest PN........: 1
macsec_drv_get_transmit_next_pn
macsec_linux: macsec_drv_get_transmit_next_pn: err 0 result 50789
KaY: to enpacket and send the MKPDU
*** MKA Basic Parameter set ***
    Version.......: 1
    Priority......: 128
    KeySvr........: 1
    MACSecDesired.: 1
    MACSecCapable.: 2
    Body Length...: 60
    SCI MAC.......: d4:25:cc:b0:25:21
    SCI Port .....: 1
    Member Id.....: - hexdump(len=12): ea fd 2f b9 9d f6 e2 17 38 0d d8 b1
    Message Number: 34070
    Algo Agility..: - hexdump(len=4): 00 80 c2 01
    CAK Name......: - hexdump_ascii(len=32):
     61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f 70   abcdefghijklmnop
     71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a 30 31 32 33 34 35   qrstuvwxyz012345
*** Live Peer List ***
    Body Length...: 16
    Member Id.....: - hexdump_ascii(len=12):
     9a fa 89 4d b4 3a 6b ac 2f b9 61 52               ___M_:k_/_aR    
    Message Number: 34452
macsec_linux: macsec_drv_get_receive_lowest_pn
macsec_linux: macsec_drv_get_receive_lowest_pn: result 1
*** MACsec SAK Use ***
    Latest Key AN....: 0
    Latest Key Tx....: Yes
    Latest Key Rx....: Yes
    Old Key AN....: 0
    Old Key Tx....: No
    Old Key Rx....: No
    Plain Key Tx....: No
    Plain Key Rx....: No
    Delay Protect....: No
    Body Length......: 40
    Key Server MI....: - hexdump(len=12): ea fd 2f b9 9d f6 e2 17 38 0d d8 b1
    Key Number.......: 1
    Lowest PN........: 1
    Old Key Server MI....: - hexdump_ascii(len=12):
     00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00               ____________    
    Old Key Number.......: 0
    Old Lowest PN........: 1
l2_packet_receive: src=d4:25:cc:b0:79:81 len=152
eth0_bridge: RX EAPOL from d4:25:cc:b0:79:81
RX EAPOL - hexdump(len=152): 03 05 00 94 01 80 60 3c d4 25 cc b0 79 81 00 01 9a fa 89 4d b4 3a 6b ac 2f b9 61 52 00 00 86 95 00 80 c2 01 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a 30 31 32 33 34 35 01 00 00 10 ea fd 2f b9 9d f6 e2 17 38 0d d8 b1 00 00 85 15 03 34 00 28 ea fd 2f b9 9d f6 e2 17 38 0d d8 b1 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 ff 00 00 10 f4 41 37 ff d5 59 6f 95 c6 3f 16 5a 9a 21 c6 b4
eth0_bridge: Ignored received EAPOL frame since no key management is configured
l2_packet_receive: src=d4:25:cc:b0:79:81 len=166
RX EAPOL-MKA:  - hexdump(len=166): 01 68 76 68 76 68 d4 25 cc b0 79 81 5e ea 03 05 00 94 01 80 60 3c d4 25 cc b0 79 81 00 01 9a fa 89 4d b4 3a 6b ac 2f b9 61 52 00 00 86 95 00 80 c2 01 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a 30 31 32 33 34 35 01 00 00 10 ea fd 2f b9 9d f6 e2 17 38 0d d8 b1 00 00 85 15 03 34 00 28 ea fd 2f b9 9d f6 e2 17 38 0d d8 b1 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 ff 00 00 10 f4 41 37 ff d5 59 6f 95 c6 3f 16 5a 9a 21 c6 b4
*** MKA Basic Parameter set ***
    Version.......: 1
    Priority......: 128
    KeySvr........: 0
    MACSecDesired.: 1
    MACSecCapable.: 2
    Body Length...: 60
    SCI MAC.......: d4:25:cc:b0:79:81
    SCI Port .....: 1
    Member Id.....: - hexdump(len=12): 9a fa 89 4d b4 3a 6b ac 2f b9 61 52
    Message Number: 34453
    Algo Agility..: - hexdump(len=4): 00 80 c2 01
    CAK Name......: - hexdump_ascii(len=32):
     61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f 70   abcdefghijklmnop
     71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a 30 31 32 33 34 35   qrstuvwxyz012345
*** Live Peer List ***
    Body Length...: 16
    Member Id.....: - hexdump_ascii(len=12):
     ea fd 2f b9 9d f6 e2 17 38 0d d8 b1               __/_____8___    
    Message Number: 34069
*** MACsec SAK Use ***
    Latest Key AN....: 0
    Latest Key Tx....: Yes
    Latest Key Rx....: Yes
    Old Key AN....: 1
    Old Key Tx....: No
    Old Key Rx....: No
    Plain Key Tx....: No
    Plain Key Rx....: No
    Delay Protect....: No
    Body Length......: 40
    Key Server MI....: - hexdump(len=12): ea fd 2f b9 9d f6 e2 17 38 0d d8 b1
    Key Number.......: 1
    Lowest PN........: 1
    Old Key Server MI....: - hexdump_ascii(len=12):
     00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00               ____________    
    Old Key Number.......: 0
    Old Lowest PN........: 1
macsec_drv_get_transmit_next_pn
macsec_linux: macsec_drv_get_transmit_next_pn: err 0 result 50790
```

And here is a sample of `ip -s macsec show`:

```
$ ip -s macsec show macsec0
38: macsec0: protect on validate strict sc on sa on encrypt on send_sci on end_station off scb off replay off 
    cipher suite: GCM-AES-128, using ICV length 16
    TXSC: d425ccb079810001 on SA 1
    stats: OutPktsUntagged InPktsUntagged OutPktsTooLong InPktsNoTag InPktsBadTag InPktsUnknownSCI InPktsNoSCI InPktsOverrun
                         0              0              0        1112            0                0           2             0
    stats: OutPktsProtected OutPktsEncrypted OutOctetsProtected OutOctetsEncrypted
                          0                7                  0                962
        1: PN 8, state on, key 4c9085d6632af3e66b5ea34602000000
    stats: OutPktsProtected OutPktsEncrypted
                          0                7
    RXSC: d425ccb025210001, state on
    stats: InOctetsValidated InOctetsDecrypted InPktsUnchecked InPktsDelayed InPktsOK InPktsInvalid InPktsLate InPktsNotValid InPktsNotUsingSA InPktsUnusedSA
                           0             18722               0             0        0             0          0            253                0              0
        1: PN 1, state on, key 4c9085d6632af3e66b5ea34602000000
    stats: InPktsOK InPktsInvalid InPktsNotValid InPktsNotUsingSA InPktsUnusedSA
                  0             0              0                0              0
```

The kernel has `CONFIG_MACSEC=y`, `CONFIG_CRYPTO_GCM=y` and `CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES=y`.

What else can go wrong with this?

Comment: Have confirmed this with the latest wpa_supplicant and also hand-configured MACSEC interfaces.  The kernel is 4.9.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in Linux 4.9, fixed in commit `b3bdc3acbb44d74d0b7ba4d97169577a2b46dc88` which went into `4.10-rc9` or thereabouts.  In cases where the MACSEC driver doesn't block on decrypting a frame but receives the decrypted frame asynchronously, the driver always marks the frame as invalid even if the decryption was successful.